# Match block of text against multiple rows

Tags: python, django, full-text-search

Trying to build a way of scanning a large block of text against individual rows that it finds a match in Django.

Lets say I have this text:

> My friends Joe Bloggs and Peter Smith are building a sandcastle with
>   their friend Jane Doe, and their dog, Benjamin

I want to scan that text and match the names to a set of "person" data that I am storing.

This is my person model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    biog = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to compare that set of text against the items in this data.

It would need to match:

Joe Bloggs

Peter Smith

Jane Doe

Benjamin

(Names can be anywhere from 1-5 words in length - they are all stored in the same row though)

How would I go about this? I'd need the function to return a list of Person ID's that it found in the text.

Tried various things like splitting the word at every break, doing a partial match then seeing if the following word was the same and continuing, but everything I've done has felt clunky and not worked as expected

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your artists are a list of tuples containing their id and full name (If you have the artists in another structure you can easily convert it).

```
artists = [ (1, 'Joe Bloggs'), (2, 'Peter Smith'), (3, 'Jane Doe'), (4, 'Benjamin') ]
t = 'Joe Bloggs\'s dog is called Benjamin. Peter Fuller and John Doe are two unkown persons.'

def findArtists (artists, text):
    return [aid for aid, name in artists if name in text]

print (findArtists (artists, t) )
```

Comment: Thanks, how scalable is this though? I currently have about 2000 person records to work with

Comment: Full text searches are always expensive, but 2000 is quite a small number. Nevertheless, you might want to skip the first step of building the tuple-list and work directly on the data structure you already have.